# using pipes for unique() function

Tags: r, pipe, unique, multiple-columns

Below is the code i used to do a mode imputation for the column status group of the dataset tan1.
How do I rewrite the same using pipes? the `unique()` function does not seem to work in pipes.

```r
NA_stat <- unique(tan1$status_group[!is.na(tan1$status_group)])

mode <- NA_stat[which.max(tabulate(match(tan1$status_group, NA_stat)))]

tan1$status_group[is.na(tan1$status_group)] <- mode
```

Also, how do I apply this same process for multiple columns?

Comment: Hard to know without knowing your data, maybe `dplyr::distinct()` could be useful, however would be great if you share with us `dput(tan1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some examples of determining and imputing the mode in a pipe.

Functions to calculate mode:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Single mode (returns only the first mode if there's more than one)
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/496488
# Modified to remove NA
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- na.omit(unique(x))
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

# Return all modes if there's more than one
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/496488
# Modified to remove NA
Modes <- function(x) {
  ux <- na.omit(unique(x))
  tab <- tabulate(match(x, ux))
  ux[tab == max(tab)]
}
```

Apply the functions to a data frame:

```
iris %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), Mode))
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1            5           3          1.4         0.2  setosa

iris %>% map(Modes)
#> $Sepal.Length
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $Sepal.Width
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $Petal.Length
#> [1] 1.4 1.5
#> 
#> $Petal.Width
#> [1] 0.2
#> 
#> $Species
#> [1] setosa     versicolor virginica 
#> Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

Impute missing data using the mode. But note that we use `Mode`, which returns only the first mode in cases where there are multiple modes. You may need to adjust your method if you have multiple modes.

```
# Create missing data
d = iris
d[1, ] = rep(NA, ncol(iris))

head(d)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

# Replace missing values with the mode
d = d %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~coalesce(., Mode(.))))

head(d)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> 1          5.0         3.0          1.5         0.2 versicolor
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa
```